# Deliver HTML5 videos from images with Azure Media Services

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, azure, azure-media-services

In my web page, it captures Camera's images (dataUrl) 30 frames/second  with 's MediaStream.
Then it sends dataUrl to my websocket server. 
My websocket server converts dataUrl to image.

I've other pages opened by other users on their computer. They should see what i'm doing in front of my camera. What i did is retreiving the images from my websocket server and play them as a "video" in an 
But the video is not fluent if network environement is not good. And it uses too much out-bandwith, it's expensive.

Is it possible that :
I just encode and save images into the repository of AMS (Azure Media Service), AMS convert them to a video stream automatically. My firends just need to play a MPEG-DASH streaming from AMS with HTML5/javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Media services doesn't support image input, you can see what is supported from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn535852.aspx

If the network environment has low capacity or drop packets then video will be troublesome in any fashion. If you can upload images to your server consistently, then perhaps display the images to them and update using a polled ajax query or a websocket.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely... i did the same research these days. you're totally right. and i'm frustrated about what Azure have today.